# Preproccessed printf function

Tags: c, macros, opencl

I'm trying to create transparent debug prtinf functions into OpenCL kernels that:

- Do not pollute the code (can be called from max one line).
- Compile away should the designated preprocessor condition prove to be untrue.

Problem is, that printf is a variadic function and I cannot wrap it in a variadic macro, since OpenCL kernel language (C99 derivate) does not support variadic macros.

```
#if DEBUG_CONDITION
printf("Any int %d\n",i);
#endif
```

Would work but would quickly render the code unreadable.

```
if(DEBUG_CONDITION) printf("Any int %d\n",i);
```

This would also work, but would require me to enable the printf pragmas, because the functions need are actually referenced in the code, even though I know they will be compiled away. (From OpenCL 2.0 on, printf will have defined sync properties, and one cannot know for sure whether the sync semantics are introduced into the binary prior to actually removing the functions or not.)

```
PRINTF("Any int %d\n",i);
```

I'm looking for something like this (or similar) that looks nice, but can fully neglect the referencing of prtintf alltogether.

Comment: How about something like `PRINTF(("any int %d", i))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kerrek SB has already suggested in his comment:

```
#if DEBUG_CONDITION
#define PRINTF(args)  printf args
#else
#define PRINTF(args)
#fi
```

and use it as

```
PRINTF(("Debugging i: %d", i ));
```

Thanks to the double paranthesis it's no variadic macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use variadic macros then why not a variadic function (which is part of the C standard)

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
inline int debug_print(char *fmt, ...)
{}
#else
int debug_print(char *fmt, ...)
{
     /* implement this I'm too lazy */
}
#endif
```

This results in an extra function call as opposed to a macro (though perhaps it can be inlined) but this shouldn't matter as it only happens when you are calling a debug statement (so who cares about the performance then)

Comment: OpenCL doesn't support variadic functions or variadic macros.  printf is a singular exception.